# How to get a stacktrace from SomeException (or any other custom Exception)?

Tags: haskell, exception

Is it possible today (GHC 8.8.3+) to extract a stacktrace from an exception that is thrown using `throwIO`, `throwM`, etc. I've spend over an hour looking at the docs of `Control.Exception` and `GHC.Stack` but couldn't find a function with type `SomeException -> CallStack` (or similar). I even tried Hoogle, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

As @Li-yao Xia said, currently there is no way to do what you want, but there are some workrounds, one of which is add the `HasCallStack` constraint to your function definition:

```hs
import GHC.Stack

head' :: HasCallStack => [a] -> a
head' [] = error "empty list"
head' (x:_) = x

foo :: HasCallStack => [a] -> a
foo xs = head' xs

goo :: HasCallStack => [Int] -> Int
goo (0:_) = error "Divid by zero"
goo xs = div 5 (foo xs)

hoo :: HasCallStack => [Int] -> Int
hoo xs = goo xs + 4
```

Load the above code into `ghci`, you can trace a call stack:

```
ghci> foo []
*** Exception: empty list
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at CallStack.hs:4:12 in main:Main
  head', called at CallStack.hs:8:10 in main:Main
  foo, called at <interactive>:14:1 in interactive:Ghci1
ghci> hoo [0, 1]
*** Exception: Divid by zero
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at CallStack.hs:11:13 in main:Main
  goo, called at CallStack.hs:15:10 in main:Main
  hoo, called at <interactive>:15:1 in interactive:Ghci1
```

However, this workaround needs explicit code changes to propagate the stack, which is the drawback.

There are also two other ways:

- Profiling: `ghc -prof -fprof-auto` and `ghci -fexternal-interpeter -prof`
- DWARF: `ghc -g`.

For more information, you can see the [posts](https://simonmar.github.io/posts/2016-02-12-Stack-traces-in-GHCi.html) by Simon Marlow, one of the Co-developers of the GHC.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that because `SomeException` does not record the trace of the exception. This is in fact the subject of an ongoing GHC proposal: https://github.com/bgamari/ghc-proposals/blob/stacktraces/proposals/0000-exception-backtraces.rst

Currently you have to manually wrap exceptions to capture the trace: define your own exception type with room for a trace, and your own throw function to capture traces.

Comment: Aargh! I so wish this was not the case!