# How to print TraceStack in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, stack-trace

I am learning `haskell-language-server` code. Add I cannot print out the tracestack.

Following 3 approaches failed.

```
defaultMain :: Recorder (WithPriority Log) -> Arguments -> IdePlugins IdeState -> IO ()
defaultMain recorder args idePlugins = do

    _ <- traceStack "aaaa" $ putStrLn "aaaaa" 


    putStrLn $ show $ length $ getCallStack emptyCallStack

    _ <- currentCallStack >>= traverse putStrLn
    _ <- exitFailure
```

Additionally

1. I added `-fprof-auto` into `.cabal` file's `ghc-options:` field.
2. I use `cabal run haskell-language-server-wrapper --enable-profiling --enable-executable-dynamic` to run `haskell-language-server-wrapper`

Could someone help?

Comment: In my test project. It is simple. Just use `cabal build --enable-profiling`.

Comment: And add `HasCallStack => ` to the function want get stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416887/how-to-get-a-stacktrace-from-someexception-or-any-other-custom-exception